# How does 'Standard Action Attacking' Work with the Big Cat animal companion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, druid, actions

I'm playing pathfinder with my friends as a hunter (ranged build) and I have an animal companion (the Big Cat animal companion archetype).  We are currently level 5, and we started at level 4 and I am confused about how many attacks my companion gets.

I am unsure which of my Big Cat's bite and claw attacks it can use as a standard action, or after moving, and whether or not it needs to use a full round action to full-attack (without moving more than a 5' step) to use all of its attacks.

Example:

Let's say I move 10 yards and then I want to attack an enemy:

- Can I attack with bite and claws?
- Only bite?
- Only claws?
- Do I need to do full round attack to get all 3 attacks?

Comment: Hi Liffuvir, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. I've removed your follow up question as we have a 1 question per post policy. However it was a perfectly valid question and you are welcome to ask it in a separate post if you wish. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 2):

> Can I attack with bite and claws?

No.

> Only bite?
> Only claws?

Either Bite or *one* claw attack.  Standard action attacks are normally only one attack, ever.

> Do I need to do full round attack to get all 3 attacks?

Yes.  At 7th level effective druid level (you get at 7th level but some classes don't) your Big Cat companion gets Pounce.  That means on a Charge action, it gets all its attacks.  Not with move.  Only with charge specifically.  Charging has limitations like distance and terrain.  It also gets other things and you will need to update its stats to reflect its new abilities.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct but could be improved by referring to the specific rulebook page or a link.